# Iterate over the types in a dicsriminated union type

Tags: typescript, union-types

In TypeScript can you iterate over all the component types of a discriminated union type? For example if I declare

```
interface Cat {}
interface Dog {}

type Animal = Cat | Dog
```

and would like to iterate over all animals in code.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "iterating" the types?

Comment: That's not a [discriminated union](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), as there is no discriminant property. Also `Cat` and `Dog` are empty interfaces and thus equivalent to each other. And it's not clear what you mean by "iterating animals"; could you show an attempt? Right now this isn't close enough to a [mre] to be answerable. My *guess* is that you are looking for runtime access to the static type system and that the answer here is "no, you might be happier making an array value and defining types from those instead of the other way around".

Comment: If you want to do this at the type level to produce another type, the better approach is to have a tuple of `[Cat, Dog]` which is a lot easier to iterate over and which you can always index with `number` when you do need a union.